# paniki, panikigi kaj panikiĝi

Tags: grammar, dictionaries, transitivity

Ĉu la verbo "paniki" estas transitiva aŭ netransitiva verbo? Laŭ [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#paniki) ĝi estas transitiva verbo, sed laŭ [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/panik.html#panik.0i) ĝi estas netransitiva verbo, kies transitiva uzo estas evitinda. Estas malkongruo inter ambaŭ vortaroj. Zamenhof neniam uzis la verbon laŭ [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/).

Ĉu oni diru "ne panikiĝu" kaj "mi panikis ŝin" aŭ ĉu oni diru "ne paniku" kaj "mi panikigis ŝin"?

---

Is the verb "paniki" a transitive or an intransitive verb? According to [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#paniki) it's a transitive verb, but according to [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/panik.html#panik.0i) it's an intransitive verb, which transitive use should be avoided. There is a disagreement between both dictionaries. Zamenhof never used the verb according to [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/).

Should one say "ne panikiĝu" and "mi panikis ŝin" or should one say "ne paniku" and "mi panikigis ŝin"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mi spontane emas uzi *paniki* kiel netransitivan verbon kaj tial por mi *ne paniku* kaj *mi panikigis ŝin* sonas pli bone. En Tekstaro tia netransitiva uzado estas pli vasta ol la alia. Ŝajnas ke Bertilo Wennergren ankaŭ preferas tian netransitivan sencon:

> [Kritikaj notoj pri la Plena Ilustrita Vortaro 2002 kaj 2005](http://de.bertilow.com/piv/index.html#parte)
>
> *“panik/o” [...] “panik/i” (tr) [...]*
>
> Tiu verbo restas transitiva. Tio apenaŭ kongruas kun la uzo de la
>   plimulto, kaj ŝajnas sufiĉe nenatura.